# What is the phase displacement of fault currents on each phase in a symmetrical fault?

Tags: three-phase, phase, fault

In a Line-Line-Line-Ground symmetrical fault, is the fault current on each phase also displaced from each other by 120°?

Comment: It might depend on the ground/neutral impedance

Comment: So if the impedances for each L-G pair is same, the phase displacement will also be same?

Comment: I'll be honest, I'm not too sure but, you can simulate this scenario easily. Do you use a simulation tool? You should probably also state that the 3 phase supply is symmetrical too.

Comment: Okay thanks! I will definitely find information on doing that.